# problem with removing previous view in a fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

i have created a fragment in android that contain 2 functions, the startview() is called at the beginning when the fragment is called, then when user click a button childfragment() is called. and at that point it should have remove the view from the startview() and then replacing it with the newview from childfragment(), and thats what i thought it would do. But instead it did not remove the old view and place the newview on top of the old view. even thought i already place  `mContainer.removeAllViews();` it did not remove the old view. what am i missing? please help.

here is the code

```
@SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
public class FragmentSideContent extends android.app.Fragment {

    //private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
    Context context;
    View view,trueview;
    ListView listView;
    ListAdapter listAdapter;

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private ViewGroup mContainer;

    int[] image = {1,2,3};
    String[] titleText = {"one","two","three","one","two","three","one","two","three","one","two","three"};
    String[] subTitleText = {"one","two","three","one","two","three","one","two","three","one","two","three"};

    public FragmentSideContent(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mInflater = inflater;
        mContainer = container;

        startview();

        return trueview;
    }

    public void startview(){
        view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sidecontent,mContainer,false);
        listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.noteList);
        listAdapter = new ListAdapter(context,image,titleText,subTitleText);
        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        trueview = view;
    }

    public void childfragment(){
        mContainer.removeAllViews();
        View newview = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sidecontent,mContainer,false);
        Fragment childFragment = new FragmentList(context);
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.child_fragment_container, childFragment).commit();

        mContainer.addView(newview);
        mContainer.addView(trueview);
        trueview = newview;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you put in your fragment layout some GroupView for do this.

fragment_layout.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             android:id="@+id/container"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent">
</FrameLayout>
```

in yout Fragment.java

```
     View view;
     Framelayout fContainer;
     @Override
      public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                               Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);

        return startView();
      }

      public View startview(){
        fContainer = (Framelayout) view.findViewById(R.id.container);
        listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.noteList);
        listAdapter = new ListAdapter(context,image,titleText,subTitleText);
        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        return view;
    }


public void childfragment(){
        fContainer.removeAllViews();
        Fragment childFragment = new FragmentList(context);
        FragmentTransaction transaction = 
        getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.container, childFragment).commit();    
    }
```

Now in your oncreateview of the other fragment (FragmentList) put the view that you want inflate.

FragmentList.java

```
@Override
          public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                   Bundle savedInstanceState) {
             View newview = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sidecontent,mContainer,false);

            return newview;
          }
```